# Can I execute Azure Automation Runbook on PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, azure

Actually I want to run these runbooks by myself, not relying on Automation Part. In this case, I can choose when to deploy them, and also it is flexible for me to choose variables.
It would be better to have some simple tutorials for me. Any Help would be grateful.
Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Azure Automation runbooks are just PowerShell Workflows, which can be run in the PowerShell ISE on your local machine as well. The only thing special about runbooks compared to PowerShell Workflows is in runbooks you can use the "Automation activities" (Get-AutomationVariable, Get-AutomationPSCredential, etc).

We don't have a blog post about this out for Azure Automation yet, but we do for Service Management Automation (the onpremise version of Azure Automation), which is very similar: http://blogs.technet.com/b/orchestrator/archive/2014/03/27/authoring-sma-runbooks-in-the-powershell-ise.aspx